# Adding Table In Cell of Another Table in docx file using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am using POI to generate a docx file. I need to create table in which a cell of table contains another table. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Instead of insert a table into a tableCell, I decided to "split" the cell, although I was not able to do it.

So, I decided to create new rows/column and merge all cells except the cells at the row/column I wanted to split.

For merging the cells I decided to follow the following steps:

For merging horizontally/vertically you need to create 2 CTHMerge and use the setVal:

- one for the cells that you will remain (STMerge.RESTART);
- a second one for the merged cells (STMerge.CONTINUE);

a) example for a horizontal merge for 2x2 table:

```
 // First Row
CTHMerge hMerge = CTHMerge.Factory.newInstance();
vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge);
table.getRow(1).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge);

 // Secound Row cell will be merged/"deleted"
CTHMerge hMerge1 = CTHMerge.Factory.newInstance();
hMerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge1);
table.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setHMerge(hMerge1);
```

b) example of a vertical merge (image with example)

```
// First Row
CTVMerge vmerge = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
vmerge.setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge);
table.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge);

 // Secound Row cell will be merged 
CTVMerge vmerge1 = CTVMerge.Factory.newInstance();
vmerge.setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
table.getRow(1).getCell(0).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge1);
table.getRow(1).getCell(1).getCTTc().getTcPr().setVMerge(vmerge1);
```